# Set maven goal during import to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

In my Java project I generate a lot of source files from IDL files by idlj-maven-plugin. It works well - it generates files before compilation when, for example, I run compile goal in Eclipse. However, I wonder if it possible to generate source files when someone imports my project in Eclipse. I mean, I would like to achieve the last step in the following scenario:

- someone clones project
- imports that project using Import the Existing Maven project
- after the above step the source files should be already generated so the user will not be confused by lack of those files (for example for a person who is not very familiar with maven and don't know that s/he needs to run goal maven to generate those files).

In the M2Eclipse description there is a statement that suggest that it is possible to set goals when projects are imported. I was looking for information about how to configure M2Eclipse to do that but with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used the `idlj-maven-plugin` myself, but we tweaked the regular "ignore-eclipse-mapping"-plugin configuration for another custom plugin we developed for our in-house needs:

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
     <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
     <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.0</version>
     <configuration>
       <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
         <pluginExecutions>
           <pluginExecution>
             <pluginExecutionFilter>
               <groupId>OUR_PLUGIN_GROUP_ID</groupId>
               <artifactId>OUR_PLUGIN_ARTIFACT_ID</artifactId>
               <versionRange>[2.3,)</versionRange> <!-- Or whatever -->
               <goals>
                 <goal>generate</goal> <!-- Or whatever idlj needs -->
               </goals>
             </pluginExecutionFilter>
             <action>
               <!-- this is what decides if the plugin should run or not -->
               <!-- Most often, you will have an <ignore/> tag instead. -->
               <execute>
                 <runOnIncremental>false</runOnIncremental>
               </execute >
             </action>
           </pluginExecution>
         </pluginExecutions>
       </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
     </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

I think [this](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html) link has some information about it.

Comment: That solved my problem (now I have some  other issues with build path but I hope that I will sove them on my own). However, I am little unsure how the lifecycle-mapping works. Does it run each specified plugin during import?

Comment: Well, some things will work automatically such as compiler settings and changing source folders. Occasionally, Eclipse will be confused and will need help, either through a plugin of its own or by ignoring the step altogether. If you understand how Maven works under the hood, it becomes quite logical. You have your plugins which attach to Maven's build life-cycle. Some plugins (such as `shade`) attach too "late" (like `package`) in the life-cycle so Eclipse simply ignores them. Other times, Eclipse needs to override Maven's plugins with its own which may or may not need to be installed.

Comment: If you haven't already, reading this link explains it all: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html